# Header font not showing up

Tags: html, css, fonts

I can't get my header fonts to show up and I don't know what to do. It worked before, but I changed something and it stopped working. For some reason, something is either canceling out or disconnecting the #play ids from everything else. The Section Styles portion is where those fonts are added, and where i tried to make the most changes to get the fonts to show up. However, nothing has worked for me so far. I would be grateful for your help.

```
  /* Structural Styles */

html {
    background-color: hsl(91, 8%, 56%);
}

body {
    background-color: hsl(58, 31%, 84%);
    font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif;
}

header {
    background-color: black;
}

p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

body>p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
}

address {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Navigation Styles */

nav a {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a:link {
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 42%, 0.4);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:visited {
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 42%, 0.4);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.7);
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 42%, 0.7);
}

a:active {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.7);
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 42%, 0.7);
}


/* Section Styles */

section.playbill h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1 header {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#play1 h1 header {
    font-family: Champagne, cursive;
}

#play1 {
    background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 88%);
}

#play2 {
    background-color: hsl(25, 88%, 73%);
}

#play2 h1 header {
    font-family: Grunge, 'Times New Roman' serif;
}

#play3 {
    background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 75%);
}

#play3 h1 header {
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

#play4 {
    background-color: hsl(296, 86%, 86%);
}

#play4 h1 header {
    font-family: Dobkin, cursive;
}


/* Description List Styles */

dt {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
}

dd {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML please?

Comment: Looking at your h1 header; is that suppose to be a class like h1 .header?
the way you suggest the HTML would be to have a header element in the h1 like <h1><header>This is my H1</header></h1>

Comment: Please post the HTML. This may have something to do with how your header is targeted. For instance, I see many "... h1 header" in your targets. This would require your header tag to be inside your h1 tag within context.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you forgot a comma between the 'Times New Roman' and serif

```
#play2 h1 header {
    font-family: Grunge, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took out the "header" portion describing the play sections. For example,

```
#play1 h1 header {
    font-family: Champagne, cursive;
}
```

should be:

```
#play1 h1 {
    font-family: Champagne, cursive;
}
```